# Producing $\mathbb{R}$ with countable amount of sets?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, baire-category

Prove, that you can't "produce" $\mathbb{R}$ with countable amount of sets, which are nowhere dense(I am not sure I said this definition correct, with nowhere dense, I mean that $Int(\overline X) = \emptyset$)

I think the proving should go that I suppose that it is possible, and somehow I have to get contradiction, but I have no idea how. :)

Edit: Answer found, thanks for help!

The answer comes directly from Baire's category theorem, which mentions an (X,d) metric space, and if it is not the empty set, and it is a complete metric space, then the statement is true for it, and obviously  $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space.

Comment: This is a special case of the famous Baire category theorem, which has many proofs online.

Comment: Can you link one of them please? :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem#Proof

Comment: What you call "nowhere common" is usually called "nowhere dense"

Comment: Okay, I am correcting it, but I found the proving, thanks! :)

Comment: If you can, please post what you found as an answer, so this question won't get bumped as "unanswered" forever.  Or if that's not possible, you can also delete the question.